# set icon uri gives me error in maps bb10

Tags: dictionary, blackberry-10

I am developing a bb10 app with maps .

I need to set pin on map but when i use:

```
flag.setIconUri(bb::UIToolkitSupport::absolutePathFromUrl(QUrl("asset:///images/pin.png")));
```

the project gives an error an is not built.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
void ApplicationUI::addPinAtCurrentMapCenter() {
qDebug("addPinAtCurrentMapCenter");
QmlDocument *qml =
        QmlDocument::create("asset:///NearMeMapsController.qml").parent(
                this);
qml->setContextProperty("app", this);
AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
QObject* mapViewAsQObject = root->findChild<QObject*>(
        QString("mapViewObj"));
if (mapViewAsQObject) {
    mapView = qobject_cast<bb::cascades::maps::MapView*>(mapViewAsQObject);
    if (mapView) {
        GeoLocation* newDrop = new GeoLocation();
        newDrop->setLatitude(30.0188);
        newDrop->setLongitude(31.4128);
        newDrop->setName("Dropped Pin");
        newDrop->setDescription("doaa");
        Marker flag;
        flag.setIconUri(bb::UIToolkitSupport::absolutePathFromUrl(QUrl("asset:///images/pin.png")));
        flag.setIconSize(QSize(60, 60));
        flag.setLocationCoordinate(QPoint(20, 59));
        flag.setCaptionTailCoordinate(QPoint(20, 1));
        newDrop->setMarker(flag);
        mapView->mapData()->add(newDrop);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: no error just the project has a red astrix and the arm files are not generated

Comment: Is an error being set on that line of code after you try building?  If not, how do you know it's to blame.  If it is, in addition to the red underline a red X to the line's right should show an error when moused over.  An error in a later stage of the compile should be reported in the console pane  (one of the tabs in the lower right by default).